# Remove table from a pages document

Tags: icloud, pages

I have added accidentally a table to my pages document on iCloud web interface. Any idea how  can I remove. I tried several different shortcuts, remove columns, rows etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select a cell within the table so that the column and row headers
   appear.
2. Then click on the nine-dot square between in the top-left
   corner between the column and row headers. The headers should
   disappear and the table should be left with a faint blue selection
   border.
3. Hit the Backspace/Delete <kbd>⌫</kbd> key on your keyboard.

The table should disappear.